# Sorting Listbox in Silverlight (Sketchflow)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, listbox, sorting, sketchflow

I have a Listbox with multiple columns and bound to a data source (XML) as shown below.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstBox1" Background="#FFC5EFFD" Margin="7,50,10,15" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding BPICollection}" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a particular column in the listbox.

Comment: This is a really good question.  The "Sketchflow" is an important clue to the actual requirement. One would hope to acheive this with some Xaml rather than resorting to code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the datagrid might be more appropriate for your situation.  It has columns, and can sort by individual columns.  It is very customizable.  If you do want to use a listbox, could you post the template and what the datasource looks like?